# Is it possible to make Case Resources a smart group?

Tags: civicase

I discovered via http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35204 that the Case Resources available in CiviCase pull from the Case Resources group.  Is there any way to make it use a Smart Group?

If not, my best workaround idea is to create the Smart Group I want, then run a script daily to synchronize that Smart Group with the Case Resources static group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses whatever group is defined in
    `<custom_templates>/CRM/Case/xml/configuration/Settings.xml`

Just note that it needs to match the "name" field in the database in civicrm_group, which is usually different from the label that appears on screen. So if you create a group in the admin pages called "Ant Exterminators", the name might actually be "Ant_Exterminators_37". This would be true even if you deleted the current Case Resources group and recreated it - it might be "Case_Resources_43".

I tried it and it works with a smart group (at least on a slightly older CiviCRM version).

Comment: Works on 4.6.2 - thanks so much!